# (How) Can I use ASP.NET Core for custom TCP packet communication?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tcp, kestrel-http-server

I have a dated game server with typical TCP packet protocol (length / type / data[length]), and my task is to find modern frameworks to rewrite it in.

Having written a (small) RESTish API in ASP.NET Core 2.1, I know that it provides DI / logging / configuration features which could perfectly replace similar functionality in the old server. I thought I could use ASP.NET Core, making it handle said TCP packets instead of HTTP requests.

Now I'm a bit stuck in where to start and if / how it would fit into ASP.NET Core.
So far I've RTFM'ed about inner ASP.NET Core workings and found some things that confused me:

- [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1) state Kestrel only supports HTTP based scenarios (don't wanna use IIS). So does the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kestrel-http-server) here on SO.
- Then I found a [project](https://github.com/davidfowl/MultiProtocolAspNetCore) claiming to add TCP support to Kestrel, yet I don't fully understand how it's done. It seems to be done by implementing a `ConnectionHandler`, but I can't see, for example, where it starts a `TcpListener` to accept new continuous connections with clients.
- With Kestrel seemingly out of the question, I thought about writing an `IHostedService` or `BackgroundService` to do all TCP communication in.
- Then I didn't know if I could use Middleware to pipe my TCP packets through (thought of an authorization and game logic middleware). [Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) quickly talk about HTTP or "web" requests, so I thought a typical middleware pipeline is out of the question too.

To sum it up, my research resulted in the following two questions:

- Can I actually use Kestrel for continuous TCP connections with binary communication?
- What is the relation between the middleware pipeline and HTTP functionality / Kestrel? Can I use a middleware pipeline in custom services for TCP communication?

Comment: Http is delivered through tcp. just different layers of networking. so port 80/443 is http and tcp. Middleware is where every request goes through, so you can inspect every http request there.

Comment: Does that mean I can inspect TCP data there too or is it only for HTTP _requests_?

Answer (score 2):

After getting back to this, I realized that [Project Bedrock](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/) is aiming to further generalize Kestrel to support completely custom protocols, not even limited to raw TCP. An overview / description can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4772).

The link above shows the current public state of the project on the GitHub repository with great practical examples. <strike>It [seems to be planned](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/issues/105) to be integrated with [whatever follows the ASP.NET Core roadmap for .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/27883), but a prerelease version compatible with .NET Core 3.1 is available and works great in my experiments.</strike> The functionality in question [no longer seems to be on the roadmap](https://github.com/davidfowl/BedrockFramework/issues/105#issuecomment-823595730).